# jQuery loop through objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, each

I have this returned from the database:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_1] => http://www.cartier.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_1] => 2530
                [boutique_dep_adv_1] => 1678.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_2] => http://www.chanel.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_2] => 2532
                [boutique_dep_adv_2] => 1136.jpg
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_3] => http://www.dior.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_3] => 2533
                [boutique_dep_adv_3] => 5488.jpg
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_4] => http://www.dolcegabbana.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_4] => 2534
                [boutique_dep_adv_4] => 2534.jpg
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_1] => http://www.harrods.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_1] => 2537
                [boutique_dep_adv_1] => 1130.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_2] => http://www.kurtgeiger.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_2] => 2538
                [boutique_dep_adv_2] => 1200.jpg
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_3] => http://www.montblanc.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_3] => 2540
                [boutique_dep_adv_3] => 38.jpg
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_4] => http://www.mulberry.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_4] => 2541
                [boutique_dep_adv_4] => 952.jpg
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_1] => http://www.paulsmith.co.uk/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_1] => 2542
                [boutique_dep_adv_1] => 2542.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_2] => http://www.prada.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_2] => 2543
                [boutique_dep_adv_2] => 2543.jpg
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_3] => http://www.smythson.com
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_3] => 2544
                [boutique_dep_adv_3] => 2544.jpg
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_4] => http://www.sunglasshut.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_4] => 2545
                [boutique_dep_adv_4] => 322.jpg
            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [boutique_dep_adv_url_1] => http://www.tedbaker.com/
                [boutique_dep_adv_id_1] => 2546
                [boutique_dep_adv_1] => 2401.jpg
            )

    )

)
```

I now need to loop through the whole thing and get all the jpg and href.

So far I've got:

```
$.each(data['boutique_dep_adv'], function(q, z){
  $.each(z, function(a, b){
    $.each(b, function(c, d){
       console.log('d= ' + d);
       console.log('c= ' + c);
    });
  });
});
```

which gives me:

```
d= http://www.cartier.com/
c= boutique_dep_adv_url_1
d= 2530
c= boutique_dep_adv_id_1
d= 1678.jpg
c= boutique_dep_adv_1
d= http://www.chanel.com/
c= boutique_dep_adv_url_2
d= 2532
c= boutique_dep_adv_id_2
d= 1136.jpg
c= boutique_dep_adv_2
etc....
```

Important to note:

- The results are grouped into 4 entries each (notice '_1','_2',etc).
- I need to be able to use those values to fill a bootstrap tile system.

I don't know why I am finding this so difficult.

Comment: I think I would have dropped the first array, I mean It dosent make sence to loop throw it.
and then you have only 2 array to run throw.
maybe Id use forEach insted of the $.each.

Comment: The first array is actually part of a bigger array and is named 'boutique_dep_adv'. Didn't include that code because I didn't think it relevant.